# AWS - losing all the www directory ! how is this possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, apache2

I am running a Dev environment on AWS EC2, Last Friday everything was working fine.

Today i figured out that Apache on dev environment doesn't work properly.

What i did last friday was, i created a new dev account for a new developer with his directory and added him to the Vhost which was nothing special.

Now when i reboot the instance on AWS its giving me warning :

```
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/dev1/www/web] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/dev2/www/web] does not exist
Warning: DocumentRoot [/home/dev3/www/web] does not exist
...
```

And when i try to su with one of the account i got

```
# su - dev1 
No directory, logging in with HOME=/
```

How can i Fix this ? and where to check for log ?

Comment: This is possible if you had another volume mounted on `/home`. If that volume was not remounted at restart or you were using ephemeral volumes.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the case, now i am looking for .. how can i attached it before reboot, because the boot is failed every time i try it without the  ESB

Comment: Your volume mount should be configured in `/etc/fstab` if you want it to auto mount it on boot. Be very careful with changes in that file, a mistake could render your system unbootable.

Comment: on my /etc/fstab file i didn't find a line for the volume in question.
its sounds it crashed, do you think it is gonna be good if i replace the current volumes with a snapshot ?

Comment: It will not be in your fstab file unless you put it there. You can do a one time mount with the `mount` command. What did you have mapped to home? Another EBS volume or ephemeral volumes?

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing the boot sequence i figured out that Apache script have been executed before Volume Mount Script, that why it can't find the root document.

To fix this using RightScale:
1 - go to your server 
2 - click on the template used to create the server (or instance) 
3 - select the Script tab 
4 - in the top on the right you have change button, click on it
5 - You can  now drag and drop to update the boot sequence (you have to put your script before apache)